# POI HSSF not iterating full set of rows

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf

Cannot iterate the full extent of rows in my `XLS spreadsheet`. The code `{sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows}` returns 33492 without raising exception, but there are about 43,000 rows??.

If I supply the right number manually the loop executes without complaint.

It must be simple answer but I cannot find one anywhere. can somebody help?

```
    try {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new 
        FileInputStream(fileLocation));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        int rows; // No of rows
        rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); //Gets => 33494

        int cols = 1; // No of columns
        int tmp = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(r);
            if (row != null) {
                cell = row.getCell(0);
                if (cell != null) {
                    System.out.println("Line number: " + r  " = " + cell);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch(Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [Javadoc says](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows--): "Returns the number of physically defined rows (NOT the number of rows in the sheet)"  (it's in braces but the "NOT" is emphasized...and i assume the key to answer your question)

Comment: Aaah .. i see. However, there are 43,000 rows in the sheet, i can see them ... are they not 'physically defined' by their very existence in the sheet?? (Uneducated Logic :) ) 

So is there a way to determine at run time how many physically defined rows there are in a sheet?? Thanks.

Comment: just a gutshot: try `getLastRowNum()` (it could be better documented, i also don't understand it...yet))

Comment: `getLastRowNum() + 1` ... ;)

Comment: Try [reading and following the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells?](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Comment: Thanks xerx593 ... and thankyou Gagravarr for the great link!!!